# Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method error while executing rest service that takes multipart parameters

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I am trying to execute a rest service which takes multipart/formdata input parameters. I am using `int-http:outbound-gateway` to execute rest service. The following is the code:

```
<int:channel id="PQcreateAttachment-Rest-Channel" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQcreateAttachment-Rest-Channel"  output-channel="PQcreateAttachment-StoredProcedure-Router" >

        <int:header-filter  header-names="accept-encoding"/>    

         <int:service-activator  ref="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" method="buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest" /> 

        <int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                    http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                    extract-request-payload="true"
                                    >
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
        <bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
        <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="Content-Type"/>
    </bean>

        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />

    </int:chain>
```

But I am getting the following error when I execute the above code.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'headerMapper' defined in file [D:\SIGAWDCS-524\customer-service\csServer\target\test-classes\CustomerService\spring-integration\Jobs\PQCreateAttachment.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    ... 41 more
```

Any ideas on what's wrong here? Please let me know if you require any additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move

```
<bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
```

outside of `<chain>` definition.

The `<chain>` supports `any`, but only those which produce `MessageHandler`.

On the other hand I don't see that you use that `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` somehow...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does that mean 'DefaultHttpHeaderMapper' not required at all? I was getting 'no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
 content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]' without using that. What could be the reason?. Any guess Artem?

Comment: That's fully different story. Lets take a look at that in a new SO question! Anyway the current your config doesn't show any usage of that bean. That's why I mean it isn't required.

Comment: Sure. I have raised a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011050/no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-error-while-executing-rest-service-that-t