# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found error while executing rest service that takes multipart parameters

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I am trying to execute a rest service which takes multipart/formdata input parameters. I am using int-http:outbound-gateway to execute rest service. The following is the code:

```xml
<int:channel id="PQcreateAttachment-Rest-Channel" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQcreateAttachment-Rest-Channel"  output-channel="PQcreateAttachment-StoredProcedure-Router" >

        <int:header-filter  header-names="accept-encoding"/>    

         <int:service-activator  ref="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" method="buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest" /> 

        <int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                    http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                    extract-request-payload="true"
                                    >
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>

        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />

    </int:chain>
```

But I am getting the following error when I execute the above code.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage] and content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
    ... 121 more
```

Here is the java code that prepares my multipart request:

```java
public Message<?> buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest(Message<?> inMessage) throws Exception{

        logger.debug(" ************** buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest Start *************************");

        String inMsgPayload = (String)inMessage.getPayload();



        SOAXml soaXml = parseSOAXml(inMsgPayload);

        String restURL      = null;
        String contentType  = null;
        String acceptHdr    = null;
        String userId = null;
        String password = null;
        String businessAreaName    = null;
        String typeName   = null;
        String attachmentLocation = null;
        String httpMethod = null;
        Message<?> outMessage = null;
        MessageHeaders inMsgHdrs = null;
        MessageBuilder<?> msgBuild = null;

        String authorization = null;
        //TODO: File location needs to be changed to standard one 
        String fileLocation = "C:\\source.xml";
            //if we reach here means, it is AWD system
            restURL     = getAwdSOAService(soaXml);

        Document document = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document(inMsgPayload);

         userId = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//userId");
         password = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//PQcreateAttachment/password");
         businessAreaName     = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//businessAreaName");
         typeName = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//typeName");
         httpMethod = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//METHOD");
         attachmentLocation = XmlParserUtil.getNodeValue(document,"//attachmentLocation");

         //Construct source xml 
         //Creating document
           Document sourceDocument = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
         Element sourceInstance = sourceDocument.addElement("createSourceInstance");
         sourceInstance.addAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1");
         Element orderItem=sourceInstance.addElement("businessAreaName");
         orderItem.setText("SAMPLEBA");
         Element orderItemDesc=sourceInstance.addElement("typeName");
         orderItemDesc.setText("SAMPLEST");
        // create source xml file
        XmlParserUtil.createXMLFileUsingDOM4J(sourceDocument, fileLocation);
        authorization = getBasicAuthorization(userId,password);

        Resource source = new ClassPathResource(fileLocation);
        Resource attachment = new ClassPathResource(attachmentLocation);


        Map<String, Object> multipartMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        multipartMap.put("source", source);
        multipartMap.put("attachment", attachment);
        logger.info("Created multipart request: " + multipartMap);  


            inMessage = buildMessageForMultipart(multipartMap); 


        //  contentType = csProps.getHttpAwdContentTypeValue();
            acceptHdr   = csProps.getHttpAwdAcceptTypeValue() ;
        //  authorization = getBasicAuthorization(soaXml.getUserid(),decriptPassword(soaXml.getPassword()));

            inMsgHdrs = inMessage.getHeaders();
            msgBuild = MessageBuilder.withPayload(inMessage).copyHeaders(inMsgHdrs);
            msgBuild.removeHeader("Content-Encoding");
            msgBuild.removeHeader("accept-encoding");
            msgBuild.setHeader(csProps.getHttpUrlHdr(), restURL);
            msgBuild.setHeader(csProps.getHttpMethodHdr(), httpMethod);
            msgBuild.setHeader(csProps.getHttpAuthorizatonHdr(),authorization );
//          msgBuild.setHeader(csProps.getHttpContentTypeHdr(), contentType);
//          msgBuild.setHeader(csProps.getHttpAcceptTypeHdr(),acceptHdr);   


        outMessage = msgBuild.build();

        logger.debug(" ************** buildHttpOutboundGatewayRequest End*************************");
        logger.debug(outMessage);
        logger.debug(" ************************************************************************");

        return outMessage;

    }
```

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Comment: Share, please, what your `buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest` returns

Comment: It returns a Message of type `org.springframework.integration.Message<?>`. Any clue now? Please let me know if you require any additional info?

Comment: Ok. Then share, please, the code of that method. You are talking about multipart, so there maybe some part which isn't serial usable, e.g. Some header in the message. That's how the entire message becomes non-serializable. Anyway that looks strange that you are going to send to rest service the message object

Comment: I have added my java code which prepares the multipart request to the SO question. Please take a look now.

Comment: Your problem is because you wrap one message to another. What your `buildMessageForMultipart(multipartMap);` does? I'm sure the simple map as payload and those header would be enough. Not sure what is the point to wrap one message to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you wrap one message to another.

What your `buildMessageForMultipart(multipartMap);` does?

I'm sure the simple map as payload and those header would be enough.

Not sure what is the point to wrap one message to another.

Comment: Super! You are correct. Wrapping out one message in another is the culprit here.   +1 for quickly pointing out the flaw .